# How to insert a binary value into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a flag to indicate that data is of binary type, or does that need to be converted to another type. For example, is there a way to do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (number) VALUES (0000 0010)
```

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (number) VALUES (2)
```

I know the above is a trivial example but basically I'm wondering if you can type a binary/hex value directly into a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [bit-value literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-value-literals.html)

```
INSERT INTO mytable (number) VALUES (b'00000010');
or
INSERT INTO mytable (number) VALUES (0b00000010)
```